# Create scoped module with providers for module feature

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, dependency-injection, nestjs

When I use the import `PolicyModule.forFeature` more than one time, the next import of the `PolicyModule` overrides gates in `PolicyStorage`.
When I try to use `PolicyProvider` in `CandidateModule`'s   `CandidateEducationService` by calling `PolicyProvider`

```
await this.policy.denyAccessUnlessGranted('canDelete', education);
```

I get the exception `Gate by entity 'CandidateEducationEntity' not found`.

I output `PolicyStorage` in `CandidateEducationService` and got array gates with `JobPolicy`

```
PolicyStorage {
  gates:
    [ { policy: [Function: JobPolicy], entity: [Function: JobEntity] } ]
}
```

But I was expecting

```
PolicyStorage {
  gates:
    [ { policy: [Function: CandidateEducationPolicy], entity: [Function: CandidateEducationEntity] } ]
}
```

I created a dynamic module `PolicyModule`

```
@Module({})
export class PolicyModule {
    public static forFeature(gates: PolicyGate[]): DynamicModule {
        const providers: Provider[] = [
            ...gates.map(gate => gate.policy),
            {
                provide: PolicyStorage,
                useValue: new PolicyStorage(gates),
            },
            PolicyProvider,
        ];

        return {
            module: PolicyModule,
            imports: [
                CommonModule,
            ],
            providers,
            exports: providers,
        };
    }
}
```

`PolicyStorage`

```
@Injectable()
export class PolicyStorage {
    constructor(private gates: PolicyGate[]) {
        console.log(this.gates);
    }

    public find(name: string): PolicyGate | null {
        return this.gates.find(policy => policy.entity.name === name);
    }
}
```

`PolicyProvider`

```
@Injectable()
export class PolicyProvider<E, P> {
    constructor(
        private readonly moduleRef: ModuleRef,
        private readonly gateStorage: PolicyStorage,
        private readonly appContext: AppContextService,
    ) {
    }

    public async denyAccessUnlessGranted(methodNames: MethodKeys<P>, entity: E, customData?: any) {
        if (await this.denies(methodNames, entity, customData)) {
            throw new ForbiddenException();
        }
    }

    public async allowAccessIfGranted(methodNames: MethodKeys<P>, entity: E, customData?: any) {
        const allowed = await this.allows(methodNames, entity, customData);
        if (!allowed) {
            throw new ForbiddenException();
        }
    }

    private async allows(methodNames: MethodKeys<P>, entity: E, customData?: any): Promise<boolean> {
        const results = await this.getPolicyResults(methodNames, entity, customData);

        return results.every(res => res === true);
    }

    private async denies(methodNames: MethodKeys<P>, entity: E, customData?: any): Promise<boolean> {
        const results = await this.getPolicyResults(methodNames, entity, customData);

        return results.every(res => res === false);
    }

    private async getPolicyResults(methodNames: MethodKeys<P>, entity: E, customData?: any): Promise<boolean[]> {
        const methodNamesArray = Array.isArray(methodNames) ? methodNames : [methodNames];
        const gate = this.findByClassName(entity.constructor.name);
        const user = this.appContext.get('user');
        const policy = await this.moduleRef.get<P>(gate.policy, {strict: false});
        const results = [];

        for (const methodName of methodNamesArray) {
            results.push(!!await policy[methodName as string](entity, user, customData));
        }

        return results;
    }

    private findByClassName(name: string) {
        const gate = this.gateStorage.find(name);

        if (!gate) {
            throw new RuntimeException(`Gate by entity '${name}' not found`);
        }

        return gate;
    }
}
```

Using module in other module. Example:
`JobsModule`

```
@Module({
    imports: [
        TypeOrmModule.forFeature(
            [
                JobEntity,
            ],
        ),
        PolicyModule.forFeature([
            {
                policy: JobPolicy,
                entity: JobEntity,
            },
        ]),
    ],
    controllers: [
        ManagerJobsController,
    ],
    providers: [
        ManagerJobsService,
    ],
})
export class JobsModule {
}
```

`CandidateModule`

```
@Module({
    imports: [
        TypeOrmModule.forFeature(
            [
                CandidateEducationEntity,
            ],
        ),
        PolicyModule.forFeature([
            {
                policy: CandidateEducationPolicy,
                entity: CandidateEducationEntity,
            },
        ]),
    ],
    controllers: [
        CandidateEducationController,
    ],
    providers: [
        CandidateEducationService,
    ],
})
export class CandidateModule {
}
```

Comment: Have a look at request-scoped providers that were introduced in nest v6, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/55067044/4694994

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Update:

Nest v6 introduced request-scoped providers, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55067044/4694994).

---

All modules and its providers are singletons. If you register a provider under the same token twice within the same module, it will be overridden.

If you have a look at the TypeOrmModule you can see it [registers its repository providers](https://github.com/nestjs/typeorm/blob/ff9ed20400b8b3d12c23edab492ceefe4b16ca86/lib/typeorm.providers.ts#L30) under a unique [custom token](https://github.com/nestjs/typeorm/blob/ff9ed20400b8b3d12c23edab492ceefe4b16ca86/lib/common/typeorm.utils.ts#L14) for each entity:

```
export function getRepositoryToken(entity: Function) {
  if (
    entity.prototype instanceof Repository ||
    entity.prototype instanceof AbstractRepository
  ) {
    return getCustomRepositoryToken(entity);
  }
  return `${entity.name}Repository`;
}
```

So in your case, you could have the functions `getPolicyProviderToken` and `getPolicyStorageToken` and both register and inject your providers under these tokens that are unique for each importing module.

Comment: I think all services are singleton it antipattern. bad, very bad.

Comment: Yes, you need to use the @Inject decorator (or create your own). Version 6 of nestjs will have transient/request-bound providers, so you will have other options than just singleton.

Comment: All providers singleton by reason nestjs creating DI graph before start application. i think making all providers by singleton antipattern, but it useful for performance.

Comment: i created dynamic name token gates `${entityName}Gates` and get gates in `PolicyProvider` by entity name `const gates = this.moduleRef.get<PolicyGateInterface[]>(entityGatesToken(name));`. No need using decorator `Inject`, but i interested in performance when use this way.

Comment: I don't expect it to have a noticeable impact on your performance but of course you'll only know when you test it. I wouldn't worry about it though